# How clear is this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

Elsewhere, there was a question about finding an elegant solution to a particular problem, and the following solution was presented.

I'm curious whether this solution is elegant **from the perspective of easy to understand** for a Ruby programmer (which I am no longer).

```
merged_file = File.open("merge_out.txt", "w")

files = ARGV.map { |filename| File.open( filename, "r") }

lines = files.map { |file| file.gets }

while lines.any?
    next_line = lines.compact.min
    file_id = lines.index( next_line )
    merged_file.print next_line
    lines[ file_id ] = files[ file_id ].gets
end
```

The question is not whether it is efficient, but just "how long does it take a Ruby programmer to understand what this does?"

Comment: The code does something, it's not _hypothetical_

Comment: Please stop changing the summary of this question.   I have not debated its closure because it is not code that I own or maintain.   However, the topic that I was asking about was nothing to do with "Merging files", it is to do with "how clear is the code".   Placing the answer of what the code does in the title detracts from the point of the question.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Titles are meant to describe **what the code does**, instead of what you want to ask. Currently, your title is poor.

Comment: @GreenAsJade You should read the [help section, about "Titling your question"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have subsequent to posting this question been educated about this.  Changing the title now on this _closed_ question doesn't help one bit.

Comment: Did someone vote to open it?  I'm not aware of that.  I already _supported_ the motion to close it, when it happened, due to the obvious breach of guidelines.   The question explicitly acknowledges that it's not my code: it's not in any way pretending that it is.

Comment: @GreenAsJade My apolegies. If you want, I can remove my comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had no trouble figuring it out what it does, but I'm not sure I'd call it "easy to understand".

All the declarations are implicit and thus if you're familiar with all the in's and outs of Array and the map method, it's pretty straight forward what the code is attempting to do. Some of the logic takes a bit of thinking about,

I did puzzle a bit over this line

```
file_id = lines.index( next_line)
```

I think the most puzzling part is the unstated requirement that the input files are already sorted. Otherwise this line doesn't work. Once I figured out that this line meant that the input files were sorted, the rest fell into place.

The exit condition is also a bit tricky to figure out.

The code really feels like a translation to ruby from a more explicitly functional language, it doesn't feel "ruby-like" at all.

Answer (score 9):

1. Took around a 100 seconds to understand. Would be twice faster if I had a commentary: `# this code merges two presorted files`.
2. All is pretty ok, but what you forgot here is to close all opened files. And it is the only reason to have a first variable declared, otherwise I would mix both `map`s together.
3. If you pass filenames via ARGV, there should be also the `merged_filename` as the first or last parameter. Or at any position and optional if you start to use some named options parsing.

So we have this:

```
files_to_merge = ARGV.map &File.method(:open)
lines = files_to_merge.map &:gets
merged_file = File.open "merge_out.txt", "w"
while lines.any?
    merged_file.print(next_line = lines.compact.min)
    file_id = lines.index next_line
    lines[file_id] = files_to_merge[file_id].gets
end
merged_file.close
files_to_merge.each &:close
```

---

But what if try to solve the problem of *mindblowing* `file_id = .index`?
You could put file handler and current line together into an Array or Hash, but I don't feel like it makes code better:

```
files_and_lines = ARGV.map(&File.method(:open)).map{ |file| {file:file, line:file.gets} }
...
loop do
    files_and_lines.select!{ |tuple| tuple[:line] }
    break if files_and_lines.empty?
    next_tuple = files_and_lines.min_by{ |tuple| tuple[:line] }
    merged_file.print next_tuple[:line]
    next_tuple[:line] = next_tuple[:file].gets
end
...
```

Trying to make it shorter didn't work for me: converting tuples into Hash pair `file->line` can't easily return file for line and `line->file` doesn't look better either because to edit a key you have to have some temporal `array` variable:

```
files_and_lines = Hash[ ARGV.map(&File.method(:open)).map{ |file| [file.gets, file] } ]
...
loop do
    break if files_and_lines.keep_if{ |line, file| line }.empty?
    array = files_and_lines.to_a.sort_by &:first
    merged_file.print array[0][0]
    array[0][0] = array[0][1].gets
    files_and_lines = Hash[array]
end
...
```

So just <s>leave Britney alone</s> don't touch it -- `.index` is ok.

Comment: [Use parentheses for non-system function calls](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-dsl-parens), you don't do this practically anywhere in your code.

Comment: @DevonParsons, why should I do what some kid on github says?

Comment: It's not some kid, it's the community driven accepted style guide.

Comment: Really, because the rule I linked to tells you exactly what to do. You seem upset about this.

Comment: The problem of modern coders is that they do not realise who is worth to listen to and who is not. And if you think code reviewing is about parentheses, you probably don't know what the good code actually is.

Answer (score 8):

It took me about five minutes to figure out, then I found that I got it wrong.  At first, I thought that it would take lines from each named file in turn.  Then, I thought that it would take the first paragraph from each file, before realizing that an "empty" line still consists of a `"\n"` and therefore wouldn't get compacted out.  In the end, I decided that it's just concatenating all the files.  Then I ran the code to discover that it does one round of mergesort.

Comment: This is exactly how I read the code, except that I never ran it and discovered that it ran just one round of merge sort.  The mental disconnect for me was seeing those file opens.  I expected the code below to deal with the files in their entirety, not just part of them.

Comment: What does "one round of mergesort" mean?  The code is supposed to deal with the files in their entirety... my understanding is that it does.

Comment: I mean that if each of the files is already individually sorted, then the code in this question lists all of the lines in sorted order.

Comment: Ah yes - that is what it indeed does... in their entirety.

Comment: That some of us were so confused about what it does is an indication that, at least for us, the code is too clever.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not sure how to go about improving it.

Comment: FWIW, I like it, once I realised how it works.   I reckon the way to improve it is a couple of comments and it's elegance would shine.   It's not my code.   If you're interested, the original question was here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20969921/elegant-way-to-merge-2-text-files-alphabetically-line-by-line-in-ruby/20970171#20970171

Answer (score 3):

I am a beginner and I don't understand what it does.

Comment: I deleted this post when I saw it in the low-quality review queue. On further reflection, it is more relevant as an answer than I initially thought. Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: @rolf I had the same thought and would have voted to close/delete if you didn't comment here.